# Custom Word Tagger

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am new to NLP and am getting to know NLTK, but am having some trouble getting off the ground on something I am trying to accomplish.

I would like to build my own word tagger such that if I pass a string like "The Porsche is red" the function would return ('Porsche','Car', 'red', 'Color').

I already have the dictionaries built that define the categories.  I am just struggling on how to get start.  Could anyone offer some assistance?

Thanks very much.

**UPDATE:** The dictionary at this time is a simple two column list in .csv format with the word and its corresponding category.

Example Link:  http://www.filedropper.com/carexampledictionary

Sincerely,
Mick

Comment: can you post a link to the dictionary (or a sample of it) and also briefly describe the format?

Answer (score 0):

I think simple lookup in the list might work. First tokenize the text, then iterate through the tokens and look up each token in the list in your lists of categories.

One problem you might have is overlap between the categories. Is there any word which occurrs in more than one category list? If so you'd need a method to disambiguate which category a given token belongs to. If not simple list-lookup should work.

More precisely, here is what I would do step-by-step:

1. Import the data into a dictionary
2. Tokenize the text
3. For each token, look up whether the token is in the keys of your dictionary
4. Tag the word according to what category it belongs to

Hope that helps.

Comment: Andreas thanks for the help! This gives me some things to think about.